# create session in c# to post data in form

Tags: c#, php, forms, session

I need to post data to a form programatically but the fields of the form are saved in the session of php. I am using C# in order to post the data to the form but it redirects me to the same page because of the aformentioned issue.

Comment: Tell you come from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737786/programatically-send-a-form-with-post/7737843#comment9417288_7737843) on SO.

Comment: yes i do. i realised the problem to why it wouldnt work

Comment: Please @michelle, show us so we can learn something and let other users to find a solution if they have your same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange coincidence. I've got something like that ...

```
class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    public CookieContainer Cookies { get; private set; }

    public CookieAwareWebClient()
    {
        Cookies = new CookieContainer();
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = base.GetWebRequest(address) as HttpWebRequest;
        if (request != null)
        {
            request.CookieContainer = Cookies;
            return request;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is fantastically vague.

You want a `CookieContainer`.